# Jquery Ajax response for Slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my jquery ajax response code:

```
$.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        data        : teststring,
        dataType    : 'html',
        success: function(response) {
                $('#ajaxResultLeft').html(jQuery(response).find('#ajaxResultLeft').html()); 

    }
    });
```

i have price slider ,if do direct form submit that slider is working,if i did by ajax means everything fine except price slider. Because of these window load function i think

```
$(window).load(function(){ function lakh_val (A, B) {...} function area_val (A, B) {..}  });
```

how to call these functions in jquery ajax response.

Comment: Not clear. I see no slider in your code?

Comment: i need call functions inside $(window).load(function(){

Comment: its not working if i use ajax

Answer (score 0):

try putting all functions called in onload like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type        : "POST",
    cache       : false,
    data        : teststring,
    dataType    : 'html',
    success: function(response) {
            $('#ajaxResultLeft').html(jQuery(response).find('#ajaxResultLeft').html()); 
            lakh_val (A, B);
            area_val (A, B);

}
});
```